# vectorizing & parallelizing the disagregation of a list

Tags: r, list, lapply, rparallel

Here's some code that generates a list of `data.frame`s and then converts that original list into a new list with each list element a list of the rows of each data frame.

Eg. 
 - `l1` has length 10 and each element is a `data.frame` with 1000 rows. 
 - `l2` is a list of length 1000 (`nrow(l1[[k]])`) and each element is a `list` of length 10 (`length(l1)`) containing row-vectors from the elements of `l1`

```
l1 <- vector("list", length= 10)
set.seed(65L)
for (i in 1:10) {
  l1[[i]] <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=10))
}

l2 <- vector(mode="list", length= nrow(l1[[1]]))
for (i in 1:nrow(l1[[1]])) {
  l2[[i]] <- lapply(l1, function(l) return(unlist(l[i,])))
}
```

**Edit** To clarify how `l1` relates to `l2`, here is language agnostic code.

```
for (j in 1:length(l1) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(l1[[1]]) { # where nrow(l1[[1]]) == nrow(l1[[k]]) k= 2,...,10
    l2[[i]][[j]] <- l1[[j]][i,]
  }
}
```

**How do I speed the creation of `l2` up via vectorization or parallelization?** The problem I'm having is that `parallel::parLapplyLB` splits lists; however, I don't want to split the list `l1`, what I want to do is split the rows within each element of `l1`. An intermediate solution would vectorize my current approach by using some `*apply` function to replace the for-loop. This could obviously be extended to a parallel solution as well.

*If I solve this on my own before an acceptable solution, I'll post my answer here.*

Comment: Don't assign to the global environment first, add to the list, and then remove from global environment. Assign straight to the list (in your for loop `l1[[i]] <- ...`) or just `l1 = replicate(10, data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol = 10)), simplify = F)`

Comment: Are your real dataframes with the same number of columns ?

Comment: @Tensibai each element of `l1` is guaranteed to have the same number of rows but not the same number of columns

Comment: I don't exactly get what you're trying to get at end, is it a transposition of each df in l1 ?

Comment: @Tensibai I'm splitting each element of `l1` into its component rows. So, rather than having a list of length 10 where each element has 1000 rows, I have a list of length 1000, where each element is a list of length 10

Comment: Right, just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Alex what I didn't get is, what's in the list of length 10, 10 vectors of 1000 values from the l1 df columns ?

Comment: Ok got it, each l2 entry is a list of the same row index for each df in l1... i.e: `l2[[2]][[3]] <- l1[[3]][2,]` (right ?)

Comment: @Tensibai Yes-- your most recent comment. I can clarify in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break the structure completely and rebuild the second list via `split`. This approach needs much more memory than the original one but at least for the given example it is >10x faster:

```
sgibb <- function(x) {
  ## get the lengths of all data.frames (equal to `sapply(x, ncol)`)
  n <- lengths(x)
  ## destroy the list structure
  y <- unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)
  ## generate row indices (stores the information which row the element in y
  ## belongs to)
  rowIndices <- unlist(lapply(n, rep.int, x=1L:nrow(x[[1L]])))
  ## split y first by rows
  ## and subsequently loop over these lists to split by columns
  lapply(split(y, rowIndices), split, f=rep.int(seq_along(n), n))
}

alex <- function(x) {
  l2 <- vector(mode="list", length= nrow(x[[1]]))
  for (i in 1:nrow(x[[1]])) {
    l2[[i]] <- lapply(x, function(l) return(unlist(l[i,])))
  }
  l2
}

## check.attributes is need because the names differ
all.equal(alex(l1), sgibb(l1), check.attributes=FALSE)

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(alex(l1), sgibb(l1), order = "relative", replications = 10)
#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#2 sgibb(l1)           10   0.808    1.000     0.808        0          0         0
#1  alex(l1)           10  11.970   14.814    11.972        0          0         0
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I get a 8.57x improvement on a real test dataset