# Rcpp - extracting rows from list of matrices / dataframes

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946004/vectorizing-parallelizing-the-disagregation-of-a-list), I've decided to go down the route of Rcpp vs convoluted syntax in R. I think this will provide better readability (and possibly also be faster).

Let's say I have a list of `data.frame`s (which I can easily convert to matrices via `as`). Given prior [answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828361/rcpp-function-to-select-and-to-return-a-sub-dataframe) [-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352208/best-way-to-convert-dataframe-to-matrix-in-rcpp) [-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719334/how-to-handle-list-in-r-to-rcpp), this seems the best approach.

```
# input data
my_list <- vector("list", length= 10)
set.seed(65L)
for (i in 1:10) {
  my_list[[i]] <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=10))
  # alternatively 
  # my_list[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=10)
}
```

What's the appropriate way to extract rows from the matrices? The goal is to create a list with each list element containing a list of the `nr`th row of each of the original list's data.frames. I've tried several different syntaxes and keep getting errors:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std:

List foo(const List& my_list, const int& n_geo) {
  int n_list = my_list.size();
  std::vector<std::vector<double> > list2(n_geo);

  // needed code....

  return wrap(list2);
}
```

**options**

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_list; i++) {
  for (int nr = 0; nr < n_geo; nr++) {
    list2[nr][i] = my_list[i].row(nr);
    // or list2[nr].push_back(my_list[i].row(nr));
    // or list2[nr].push_back(as<double>(my_list[i].row(nr)));
    // or list2[nr].push_back(as<double>(my_list[i](nr, _)));
  }
}

// or:
NumericMatrix a = my_list[1] 
... 
NumericMatrix j = my_list[10]

for (int nr = 0; nr < n_geo; nr++) {
  list2[nr][1] = // as above
}
```

None of these are working for me. What am I doing wrong? Here are the errors I receive from my above syntax choices.

> error: no matching function for call to 'as(Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Row)'

or

> error: cannot convert 'Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Row {aka Rcpp::MatrixRow<14>}' to 'double' in assignment

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me. Can show example R objects for your input (corresponding to `my_list`) and desired output?

Comment: So you are trying to write the operation that creates `l2` in your other question, using Rcpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// x[[nx]][ny,]  ->  y[[ny]][[nx]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Transform(Rcpp::List x) {
    R_xlen_t nx = x.size(), ny = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericMatrix>(x[0]).nrow();
    Rcpp::List y(ny);

    for (R_xlen_t iy = 0; iy < ny; iy++) {
        Rcpp::List tmp(nx);
        for (R_xlen_t ix = 0; ix < nx; ix++) {
            Rcpp::NumericMatrix mtmp = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericMatrix>(x[ix]);
            tmp[ix] = mtmp.row(iy);
        }
        y[iy] = tmp;
    }

    return y;
}

/*** R

L1 <- lapply(1:10, function(x) {
    matrix(rnorm(20), ncol = 5)
})

L2 <- lapply(1:nrow(L1[[1]]), function(x) {
    lapply(L1, function(y) unlist(y[x,]))
})

all.equal(L2, Transform(L1))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "R" = lapply(1:nrow(L1[[1]]), function(x) {
        lapply(L1, function(y) unlist(y[x,]))
    }),
    "Cpp" = Transform(L1),
    times = 200L)

#Unit: microseconds
#expr    min      lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
#  R 254.660 316.627 383.92739 347.547 392.7705 1909.097   200
#Cpp  18.314  26.007  71.58795  30.230  38.8650  945.167   200

*/
```

---

I'm not sure how this will scale; I think it is just an inherently inefficient transformation. As per my comment at the top of the source, it seems like you are just doing a sort of coordinate swap -- the `ny`th row of the `nx`th element of the input list becomes the `nx`th element of the `ny`th element of the output list:

```
x[[nx]][ny,]  ->  y[[ny]][[nx]]
```

---

To address the errors you were getting, `Rcpp::List` is a generic object - technically an `Rcpp::Vector<VECSXP>` - so when you try to do, e.g.

```
my_list[i].row(nr)
```

the compiler doesn't know that `my_list[i]` is a `NumericMatrix`. Therefore, you have to make an explicit cast with `Rcpp::as<>`,

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix mtmp = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericMatrix>(x[ix]);
tmp[ix] = mtmp.row(iy);
```

---

I just used `matrix` elements in the example data to simplify things. In practice you are probably better off coercing `data.frame`s to `matrix` objects directly in R than trying to do it in C++; it will be much simpler, and most likely, the coercion is just calling underlying C code, so there isn't really anything to be gained trying to do it otherwise.

---

I should also point out that if you are using a `Rcpp::List` of homogeneous types, you can squeeze out a little more performance with `Rcpp::ListOf<type>`. This will allow you to skip the `Rcpp::as<type>` conversions done above:

```
typedef Rcpp::ListOf<Rcpp::NumericMatrix> MatList;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Transform2(MatList x) {
    R_xlen_t nx = x.size(), ny = x[0].nrow();
    Rcpp::List y(ny);

    for (R_xlen_t iy = 0; iy < ny; iy++) {
        Rcpp::List tmp(nx);
        for (R_xlen_t ix = 0; ix < nx; ix++) {
            tmp[ix] = x[ix].row(iy);
        }
        y[iy] = tmp;
    }

    return y;
}

/*** R

L1 <- lapply(1:10, function(x) {
    matrix(rnorm(20000), ncol = 100)
})

L2 <- lapply(1:nrow(L1[[1]]), function(x) {
    lapply(L1, function(y) unlist(y[x,]))
})

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "R" = lapply(1:nrow(L1[[1]]), function(x) {
        lapply(L1, function(y) unlist(y[x,]))
    }),
    "Transform" = Transform(L1),
    "Transform2" = Transform2(L1),
    times = 200L)

#Unit: microseconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#         R 6049.594 6318.822 7604.871 6707.242 8592.510 64005.190   200
# Transform  928.468 1041.936 3130.959 1166.819 1659.745 71552.284   200
#Transform2  850.912  957.918 1694.329 1061.183 2856.724  4502.065   200

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the continued edits. I'm getting a ~11x speed up vs my naive R method, which is better than the ~8.5x speed up via the prior solution from sgibbs... And, as originally noted, the readability is substantially improved.